# Convert SPRoleAssignment to Client.RoleAssignment in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am having this error at the moment.

How do I convert SpRoleAssignment to Client.RoleAssignment in SharePoint 2010

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you get SPRoleAssignment objects, why not just use them?